# Make [screen] a synonym of [display]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I suggest that [screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen) (585 questions) is added as a synonym of [display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display) (2855 questions). These are the excerpts:

> display: Generally a visual screen used to display graphical or text output
>
> screen: The (usually) LCD display integrated into portable computing products, or external monitor/television connection to same.

Comment: We will likely need a crew organized to clean up any posts in the 585 that are clearly not ready for the merge. Great post. +1 Let’s see f there’s anything we’re missing where these should stay distinct.

Comment: There are questions like [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159251/connect-macbook-to-projector-without-displayport) that use `display` when talking about projector (there is a `projector` tag but it has no definition).  I think there is a difference between questions like *"How do I move the dock to the top of my screen"* and *"What cable do I use to connect an external xyz display"* but the two words are pretty much synonyms and the tag descriptions don't help differentiate so perhaps merge these and make a new tag `External display`?